# css3pie - element dissappers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css3pie

When I use css3pie file on my button, the element(Button) is no longer visible. But when I Click on where the button should be, it functions properly.. I have no idea whats wrong..
here is my HTML

```
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Send">
```

and my CSS

```
.btn{
width:130px; 
margin-left:95px; 
font-weight:bold;
border-radius:28px; 
behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

adding `behavior: url(PIE.htc);` makes my element disappear in ie...

Comment: in which version of ie are you not able to see the button. It is working fine on my compatibility view.

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer are you seeing the problem in? Sometimes adding `position:relative;` to either this element or it's parent can fix this issue. Have a look at http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/ too.

Comment: i was having erron in IE8.. Adding `position : relative` helped.. thnx a lot guyz :)

Comment: @OllyHodgson, you should add that as an answer so that harsh-shah can mark it accepted.

Comment: @JasonMArcher Good point. Done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Internet Explorer are you seeing the problem in? Sometimes adding `position:relative;` to either this element or it's parent can fix this issue.

Have a look at http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/ too.